# Why luci can not execute dispatcher target for entry

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

I am new in Luci/lua,work on **LuCI 15.05-154-gb81a22b** and lua 5.1 Face problem to execute view show me bellow error

**Controller syntax is bellow**

```
e=entry({"admin","network","macclone"},arcombine(template("admin_network/mac_clone")),_("MacClone"),14)
            e.leaf=true
```

Controller successfully call view page.

**View**

```
<%#
 Copyright 2008-2009 Steven Barth <steven@midlink.org>
Copyright 2008-2015 Jo-Philipp Wich <jow@openwrt.org>
Licensed to the public under the Apache License 2.0.
-%>
<%-+header-%>
<div  id="cbi-network">
<h2>hello</h2>
</div>
<%-+footer-%>
```

View execute with error

[image]

Why this error appear?How to solve this error?

Note: header load necessary css files like:bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

It says that it cant find the template admin_network/mac_clone. You need to add a model page mac_clone. Also change the 
`arcombine(template("admin_network/mac_clone"))` 
to `cbi("mac_clone")`